# Calculating Integrals

Tags: c++, math, integral

I am trying to calculate a integral in C++ and i am trying to use [Simpson's 3/8 Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Simpson%27s_3/8_rule) (Also known as Simpson's second Rule) to calculate it. I wrote a program but it gives the wrong result. When i used the same rule on paper it works. I don't know what's wrong.
simpsons.cpp :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

double f(int x) {
  return 3*(x*x)+2*x+5;
}

float integralf(int lower_end, int high_end) {
  int a = lower_end;
  int b = high_end;
  double area = 0.0;
  area = ((b - a)/8)*(f(a) + 3*f((2*a+b)/3) + 3*f((a+2*b)/3) + f(b));
  return area;
}

int main() {
  int lower = -3;
  int high = 5;
  std::cout << integralf(lower, high) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

It gives 194 but answer is 208. I tried the same integral with Reimann sum technique and it gave 166.24.
reimann.cpp :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

double f(int x) {
  return 3*(x*x)+2*x+5;
}

double integral(double low_end, double high_end, double steps) {
  double step = (high_end - low_end)/steps;
  double area = 0.0;
  double y = 0;
  double x = 0;

  for(int i=0;i<=steps;++i) {
    x = low_end + i * step;
    y = f(x);
    area += y * step;
  }

  return area;
}

int main() {
  int low_end = -3;
  int high_end = 5;
  int steps = 100;
  std::cout << integral(low_end, high_end, steps) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I don't know what is wrong. Is there a better way to calculate integrals in cpp? Every advice is welcome.

**SOLUTION**

**Edit** : I did it. Final version of code (simpsons.cpp) :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

double f(double x) {
  return 3*(x*x)+2*x+5;
}

float integralf(double lower_end, double high_end) {
  double a = lower_end;
  double b = high_end;
  double h = (b - a)/3;
  double area = 0.0;
  area = ((3*h)/8)*(f(a) + 3*f((2*a+b)/3) + 3*f((a+2*b)/3) + f(b));
  return area;
}

int main() {
  int lower = -3;
  int high = 5;
  std::cout << integralf(lower, high) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

It gave the answer 208.

Comment: `double h = (b - a) / 3;` this is integer division

Comment: i edited the program and deleted the double h line and used (b-a)/8 directly. Edited the post you can see the new version. Now it gives 194. Is it the best answer i can get? I know wolframalpha uses ai or something like that to calculate.

Comment: 1) Divisions like `(2*a+b)/3` don't do what you think they do. 2) The signature `double f(int x)` makes no sense. The parameter should have `double` type, not `int`.

Comment: *"When i used the same rule on paper it works.*" -- this is good. Next step: step through your program (with a debugger) and see where its calculation differs from yours. You might find this is easier if you break up your calculation (bring back `h`).

Comment: IT WORKS! Thanks every one. For real, i mean i didn't have to do that program but i stuck on my mind you know. I wanted to do that and i did. Thanks to you. I will add the final version of the code by editing.

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final version of code (simpsons.cpp) :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

double f(double x) {
  return 3*(x*x)+2*x+5;
}

float integralf(double lower_end, double high_end) {
  double a = lower_end;
  double b = high_end;
  double h = (b - a)/3;
  double area = 0.0;
  area = ((3*h)/8)*(f(a) + 3*f((2*a+b)/3) + 3*f((a+2*b)/3) + f(b));
  return area;
}

int main() {
  int lower = -3;
  int high = 5;
  std::cout << integralf(lower, high) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

It gave the answer 208.